# COMO QUITAR FILAS REPETIDAS EN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Amigos buenas noches, espero y me puedan ayudar...

tengo el siguiente inconveniente o bueno no es un inconveniente es mas bien desconocimiento...

Tengo esta tabla en Mysql

[image: Tabla de existencias de inventario]

y necesito hacer una seleccion a la base de datos y me pueda mostrar le existencia a la fecha y lo estoy haciendo de esta forma.

[image: Esta es la imagen de la consulta y su respectivo resultado]

Como se observa en la primer imagen en los movimientos de inventario, selecciono el saldo + la entrada - la salida para poder obtener asi el total, ¿por que le pongo en el where <= 'Fecha'? por que si en el software hago una consulta al dia 18 por ejemplo la consulta no me puede retornar null ya que del dia anterior hay existencias en la bodega, ahora el error radica y si se fijan es en el articulo repetido en la bodega repetida, me explico. la cantidad 8 es de un movimiento en un dia pasado pero la cantidad neta a la fecha es 1.

LA PREGUNTA PRINCIPAL TENIENDO EN CUENTA LO ANTERIOR ES ¿COMO PUEDO HACER PARA RECUPERAR EL PRIMER REGISTRO DEL ARTICULO DUPLICADO EN LA BODEGA DUPLICADA, YA QUE ASÍ COMO ESTA TENGO UNA INFORMACIÓN ERRONEA?

Le agradeceria enserio en el alma a la persona que me desee ayudar con este tema ya que se que es sencillo pero desconozco su solucion.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Supongo que lo que quieres es que te agrupe (**GROUPED_BY**) por el par formado **ART_CODIGO** y **BOD_CODIGO**. Aunque tengo la duda si pueden haber entradas de un mismo producto, misma bodega el mismo día.

Comment: Daniel, ¿podrías [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/173789/edit), poniendo un ejemplo de los resultados que esperas obtener? No tiene por qué ser una captura de imagen, sino un texto con los resultados en filas/columnas.

Comment: La pregunta es fijense solo en la primera y segunda columna y hagan de cuenta que estan haciendo una consulta desde un software de inventario y quieren saber cuales son sus existencias de mercancia, hasta ahi todo va bien, pero si yo hago la consulta al dia 18, como no tengo informacion por eso en el where es <= 'FECHA' para que me traiga el saldo al dia anterior, ahora bien como el articulo ya tenia movimientos de fecha anterior por eso sale del 17 y del 15 pero la fecha al 17 es 1 por eso solo necesito conservar la primera fila de la consulta cuando el articulo esta en la bodega repetida.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrías probar con esto, espero que te sirva.

```
SELECT E.ART_CODIGO, E.BOD_CODIGO, (E.EXIS_SALDO + E.EXIS_ENTRADA - E.EXIS_SALIDA) AS CANTIDAD, E.EXIS_FECHA FROM EXISTENCIA E
INNER JOIN ARTICULO A ON A.ART_CODIGO = E.ART_CODIGO
INNER JOIN BODEGA B ON B.BOD_CODIGO = E.BOD_CODIGO 
WHERE E.EXIS_FECHA <= "2018-06-17"
GROUP BY E.ART_CODIGO, E.BOD_CODIGO
ORDER BY 1 DESC,2 DESC, 4 DESC;
```